# On ramification index of a congruence subgroups at cusps

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

I am trying to solve this [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlOMP.png) from Koblitz "Introduction to Elliptic Curves and modular forms" page 144,
where $\Gamma=\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}),$ and $T=\left(%
\begin{array}{cc}
  1 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 \\
\end{array}%
\right).$ I showed (a) as follow :

Let $\beta\in(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_{\infty}$ then we can write $\beta=\alpha\gamma\alpha^{-1}$ with $\gamma\in\Gamma'$ so we have :
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \beta.\infty=(\alpha\gamma\alpha^{-1}).\infty=\infty &\Leftrightarrow& (\alpha\gamma).\alpha^{-1}\infty=\infty \\
                               &\Leftrightarrow& (\alpha\gamma).s=\infty \\
                               &\Leftrightarrow& \alpha^{-1}\alpha\gamma.s=\alpha^{-1}.\infty\\
                               &\Leftrightarrow& \gamma.s=s \\
                               &\Leftrightarrow& \gamma\in\Gamma'_s \\
                               &\Leftrightarrow& \beta\in \alpha\Gamma'_s\alpha^{-1} 
\end{eqnarray*}
finally $(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_{\infty}=\alpha\Gamma'_s\alpha^{-1}$

For (b) : we have $(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_{\infty}\subset \Gamma_\infty=\{\pm I\}.<T>$ and $[\Gamma_\infty :(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_{\infty}]<\infty$ so if we take $h=[\Gamma_\infty :(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_{\infty}]$ then we have : $(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_{\infty}=\{\pm I\}.<T^h>=\alpha\Gamma'_s\alpha^{-1}(*)$ I'm stuck here.

**My question is : How I can conclude (IIa) and (IIb) from  $(*)$ ?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a slight error: $(*)$ implicitly assumes that $-I\in\Gamma_s$.

If $-I\in\Gamma'$, then $\{\pm I\}\subset(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_\infty\subset\Gamma_\infty=\{\pm I\}\cdot\langle T\rangle.$ As you've shown, it follows that 
$$\alpha\Gamma_s'\alpha^{-1} = \{\pm I\}\cdot\langle T^h\rangle = \{\pm T^{nh}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$$and hence that $$\Gamma_s = \pm\alpha^{-1}\{T^{nh}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}\alpha.$$

Here $h$ is the minimal positive integer such that $T^h\in(\alpha\Gamma_s'\alpha^{-1})_\infty$, which exists as $[\Gamma_\infty:(\alpha\Gamma_s'\alpha^{-1})_\infty]<\infty$.

However, if $-I\notin \Gamma'$, then either $T^h$ or $(-T)^h$ is an element of $\alpha\Gamma_s'\alpha^{-1}$, but not both, so $(*)$ does not hold in this case. Either $$(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_\infty= \langle T^h\rangle = \{ T^{nh}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$$or$$(\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_\infty=\langle (-T)^h\rangle = \{ (-T)^{nh}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}.$$

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo!

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you explain to my a bit more why $(\alpha \Gamma ' \alpha^{-1} )_{\infty}=\{\pm I \}.<T^h>$ if $-I\in\Gamma'$ ?

Comment: Thanks Mathm0123 for the explanation.

Comment: You probably shouldn't accept the answer until you're fully happy with it! I've made an edit. In particular, I haven't defined $h$ in the same way as you (although I think your way does work out to be correct in the first case).

Comment: In general if $G=<a>$ a cyclic groups and $H\subset G$ a subgroups of finite index $[G:H] =h$ then we have $h$ the smallest integer such that $a^h\in H$  and so $H=<a^h>$?!

Comment: Yes. But the group $\pm I\cdot \langle T\rangle$ is not cyclic. In the first case, the quotient is cyclic, but in the second case it isn't.

Comment: I have another question, in the case $-I\notin \Gamma'$ why $T^h$ or $(-T)^h\in (\alpha\Gamma'\alpha^{-1})_{\infty}$  ?